# Unbind c-n and c-p from tmux

Tags: tmux

I want to totally unbind the next-window and previous-window command from tmux, here is what I have in my tmux conf

```
unbind C-n
unbind n
unbind C-p
unbind p
```

It works well on ubuntu, but on Mac it doesn't work. tmux lsk will still give me:

```
bind-key    -T prefix C-n              next-window
bind-key    -T prefix C-o              rotate-window
bind-key    -T prefix C-p              previous-window
bind-key    -T prefix C-q              send-prefix
```

I'm using tmux 2.1 on Mac and tmux 2.0 on ubuntu

If this helps, my tmux config repo is at https://github.com/ShengYun/dbstmux